# How to resolve sap and sapv namespace in xaml files

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, workflow-foundation-4

New to WPF and XAML.  What does sap and sapv name spaces in xaml files mean and how do I resolve them?  Thanks.

Comment: Those are custom namespaces. They're defined in some dll we don't know of. Post the relevant XAML.

Comment: Took a stab at what you might be trying, but as HighCore said, we don't really know what you're doing without the XAML in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be a comment, but won't fit.

It sounds like you may well be referencing Workflow dlls without having added the relevant references (it's a slight stretch based on your Workflow tag).

`sap` and `sapv` often reference the `System.Activities.Presentation.dll`, which you may not have added to your project.

e.g:

```
xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
```

Examples and advice here (depending on what it is you're doing): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489419.aspx

Comment: Thank you I am trying to find  the MSN blog that I copied the code from to post it here.  So far no luck. But you are correct it is Workflow related. And I d have  the System.Activities.Presentation.dll referenced in my project in VS2010

Comment: Can you not just grab the code from within the xaml file giving you the compilation error?

Comment: I solved my problem in C#. So I dont even need to figure out this question now until next time I get stuck.But thanks for your help and followup.I will grant you the answer.  Thanks